# Создание JAR-архива в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Проблема довольно странная.

Есть проект на `JAVA`, работаю в `Eclipse`. Создаю `JAR`-архив: `File->export->Runnable JAR File`.
Соответственно, получаю `JAR`-файл, который по двойному клику выполняется, в частности, пишет некий лог.

Теперь в проект вношу изменения. Для простоты уже просто вывожу в начале в лог дополнительные строки. Запускаю из `Eclipse` - все работает с учетом изменений. Из измененного проекта создаю `JAR`-архив - изменений нет! Доп. информация не выводится. Уже все перепробовала, ничего не понимаю. Такое ощущение, что он берет только одну какую-то старую версию и запаковывает в `JAR`.

Что это вообще может быть?

Comment: а вы удаляете старый файл перед тем как экспортнуть новый?

Comment: там при экспорте галка есть, перезаписывать ли существующий файл

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте 
**Project > Clean**